# How am I able to embed a blob video file from an API call in the HTML and play it within the same HTML page?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html5-video, blob

I am currently having a few methods in the following where **handlePdfBlob** handles fileType that are in "***pdf***" while the rest are for other file types where the blob data will be downloaded using **handleBlob** method. I would like to have a seperate method for fileType that are in "***mp4***" where the video is not downloaded but being played in the same HTML page upon clicking on a button. I have look at the **HTMLVideoElement** but I am not sure how am I able to assign the blob data object that is given in the response body of the API to the HTMLVideoElement "**video**" tag in the HTML file. What are some suggested ways that I am able to achieve playing the video directly in the HTML page after making the API calling from the HTML page?

```
  downloadSampleFile(apiUrl: string, fileName: string, fileType: string, req: any = {}): void {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    this.http.get<Blob>(apiUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
      .subscribe(((res: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
        if (fileType.match("pdf")) {
          this.handlePdfBlob(res.body!, fileName, fileType);
        }
        else {
          this.handleBlob(res.body!, fileName, fileType);
        }
      }));
  }

  private handlePdfBlob(data: Blob, fileName: string, fileType: string): void {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url);
  }

  private handleBlob(data: Blob, fileName: string, fileType: string): void {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.download = fileName + "." + fileType;
    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.click();
  }
```

I have tried to create a new method for this and return the URL string.

`const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);`

However, I am not sure why the url is returning undefined in the console.

Comment: what type of file did you received from api for .mp4 ?

Comment: @GRD The return response is a blob object

Comment: I don't use Angular or TypeScript so they might have different names for this: `var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);` should fix the "undefined" issue. Also `data` might be a reserved **keyword** so maybe rename your variable as `inData` or such. You need to create a `<video>` tag and in JS access it by its ID like example `myVid.src = url; myVid.load();`